# Disable cookie checks against Public Suffix List in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, heroku, public-suffix-list

We have a collection of apps, and we would like to test them before merging PR's using Heroku's [Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps).

The login is stored in a cookie that is shared across these apps. Since `herokuapp.com` is listed under [Public Suffix List](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com), we can't use the heroku-provided domain for testing apps because cookies don't get shared on that domain.

Is there an easy way to disable the domain the check against the Public Suffix List in Chrome, or can we locally exclude/override `herokuapp.com` from the list?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Late to the party, but do you want to mock the behaviour in your dev environment and test if your app is working fine?